# Change color of an svg dynamically and apply as texture in three.js

Tags: javascript, svg, three.js

i´m trying to create a configurator with three.js but im at the point that i need to change the color of the product dinamycally, i though that i can use an svg as texture, change the fill property of the svg and update the texture easily, but im not having good results

at the moment what i have is

-A 3D model with an svg applied as texture with a TextureLoader, but the svg is placed in a external file ("images/texture.svg")(also three.js is reducing the size of the texture, but i think its a mapping problem)

-The svg is separated in layers, so i can manually change the color and apply it

But im trying to make it dynamic, you choose a color and it automatically updates the svg applied as texture

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I forked someone else's fiddle to show the solution. I added a click function which modifies the SVG and redraws the material on the model.

See http://jsfiddle.net/L4pepnj7/

Click anywhere on the example to change the color of the circle in the SVG.

The operation which converts the SVG to an encodedURI is to intensive to have in a constant loop, but you can put the color change in a click event while the renderer is doing it's own thing. I added a function called "clickBody" to the existing fiddle which changes the color of one of the SVG elements.

```
var mesh;
var scene = new THREE.Scene();

var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, 500 / 400, 0.1, 1000);
camera.position.z = 10;

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: true
});
renderer.setSize(500, 400);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var svg = document.getElementById("svgContainer").querySelector("svg");
var svgData = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(svg);

var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
var svgSize = svg.getBoundingClientRect();
canvas.width = svgSize.width;
canvas.height = svgSize.height;
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var img = document.createElement("img");
var material;
img.setAttribute("src", "data:image/svg+xml;base64," + window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(svgData))));

img.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    var texture = new THREE.Texture(canvas);
    texture.needsUpdate = true;
    var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(3, 50, 50, 0, Math.PI * 2, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        map: texture
    });
    material.map.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
    mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    scene.add(mesh);
};



var colors = ["red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue"];


var c = 0;

function clickBody() {
    document.getElementById("test").setAttribute("fill", colors[c]);
    var svgData = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(svg);
    img.setAttribute("src", "data:image/svg+xml;base64," + window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(svgData))));
    img.onload = function() {
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        var texture = new THREE.Texture(canvas);
        material.map = texture;
        material.map.needsUpdate = true;
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    }
    c = c + 1;
    if (c == colors.length) {
        c = 0;
    }
}
document.body.addEventListener("click", clickBody)

var render = function() {
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
    mesh.rotation.y += 0.01;
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
};


render();
```

Comment: so basically what this code is doing is rendering the updated texture only in the clickevent?does the SVG size affect to the UV mapping or is proportional?I mean, a  800x800 svg texture will be textured in the same UV space than a 300x300?

Comment: @robertgarcia Yes. So in your case, you have a product configurator to change the graphics on a 3d model. In this case if the SVG is updated via a separate UI, such as enabled via [svg-edit](https://github.com/SVG-Edit/svgedit) you can then trigger the code to redraw the svg as an encoded uri, and set it as the new texture of the material.

Comment: well the point is not to change the graphics at all, simply i loaded a 3D model and you can choose between different designs (textures in SVG), once you have the one you want you can change the SVG properties of the texture with your example, with a color picker interface, so yours does the trick, thanks!

Comment: I don't mean to criticize your approach, as I do not understand your project constraints. However, what you describe seems like it could be accomplished with PNG versions of the SVG images. Using SVG with Three.js requires extra, intensive steps to convert the image to raster with JS on the user's CPU, and uses quite a bit of ram. Unless you have a specific reason to use SVG, convert the SVG image to PNG using illustrator or the like, and serve PNG images to the user. Better would be DDS, which is GPU native, which keeps ram use at a fraction of SVG, PNG and JPG ram allocation in webGL.

Comment: The point of use PNG is that you only can use determined colors, but im using svg since you can use any HEX color changing the fill property

Maybe i explain badly the situation, lets say i have a 3D shirt with a blue line across, the background color of the shirt is green, with an SVG i can change the background color and the line color dinamycally to whatever color i want lets say #FFFFFF, with PNG i can store maybe 5 diferent textures with their respective colors, so the colors variables are limited to 5

Of course i dont consider your comment a critic, is very welcome

Comment: Gotcha, that is a viable use case for SVG from an ease and portability standpoint. My only advice going forward would be to use the browser debugger to watch your memory footprint. You may need to do a littlle more work than the answer here implies which includes disposing of and creating brand new materials and texture objects. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13914959/three-js-memory-management