# Three.js - How to manipulate an SVG graphic's attributes mapped to an external geometry

Tags: javascript, svg, three.js, texture-mapping

I've recently begun learning Three.js in order to create a *3D kit designer* for a college project.

From my research, I've learnt the fundamentals about setting up scenes, scene objects, geometries, materials and textures.

I am at the point where I have set up a scene, imported an external geomertry, a converted .json model from Blender, and successfully mapped a simple SVG graphic as a texture.

[image: Scene screenshot]

However, I'm stuck. I somehow have to figure out a way to customise the colours of the SVG (*jersey design*) on the model.

My logic was that I would manipulate the mapped SVG's html element attributes in real time using JavaScript.

Only I noticed a few problems with my plan:

1. Models and textures are set up exclusively in Three.js before being added via only a canvas element into the browser, i.e I can't view the SVG attributes in the browser inspector and manipulate them.
2. Three.js's [texture loader](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/loaders/TextureLoader) appears only to accept file paths as parameters, instead of say, the raw SVG code.

When receiving feedback, I was advised, vaguely, to attempt to see if Three.js supports functionality that allows manipulation of SVGs as textures, or if I could manually access the SVG attributes.

I scoured the web and documentation to no avail, and here I am.

So my question remains:

**How would one access and manipulate the propreties of an SVG graphic mapped as a texture to an external geometry in Three.js?**

Have I missed anything or overlooked different methodologies? Regardless, cheers for taking the time to read, offer feedback, and help.

Sound, Papa bless.

Comment: I guess the basic idea is to create a new SVG on the fly and set that as texture.

Comment: Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45928882/1461008) by @Radio is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to dynamically generate a texture programmatically, actually an array of pixels converted to a texture. Then use that texture in a custom shader.

Take a look at my article: [Using a Dynamic Texture inside Custom Shaders](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/using-dynamic-texture-inside-custom-shaders).

This is not using plain Three.js unfortunately but the Autodesk Forge Viewer, however the approach remains the same, since it is based on Three.js code as well.

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Generates custom shader using an updatable 
// dynamic texture generated programmatically
//
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
createShader (options) {

  // Vertex Shader code
  const vertexShader = options.vertexShader || `
    attribute float pointSize;
    attribute vec4 color;
    varying vec4 vColor;
    void main() {
      vec4 vPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
      gl_Position = projectionMatrix * vPosition;
      gl_PointSize = pointSize;
      vColor = color;
    }
  `

  // Fragment Shader code
  const fragmentShader = options.fragmentShader || `
    uniform sampler2D texture;
    varying vec4 vColor;
    void main() {
      vec4 tex = texture2D(texture, gl_PointCoord);
      if (tex.a < 0.2) discard;
      if (vColor.a == 0.0) {
        gl_FragColor = vec4(tex.r, tex.g, tex.b, tex.a);
      } else {
        gl_FragColor = vColor;
      }
    }
  `

  const tex = options.texture || defaultTex

  // Shader material parameters
  const shaderParams = options.shaderParams || {
      side: THREE.DoubleSide,
      depthWrite: false,
      depthTest: false,
      fragmentShader,
      vertexShader,
      opacity: 0.5,
      attributes: {
        pointSize: {
          type: 'f',
          value: []
        },
        color: {
          type: 'v4',
          value: []
        }
      },
      uniforms: {
        texture: {
          value: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(tex),
          type: 't'
        }
      }
    }

  // creates shader material
  const material =
    new THREE.ShaderMaterial(
      shaderParams)

  const generateTexture = (size, radius) => {

    const pixels = []

    for (let u = 0; u < size; ++u) {

      for (let v = 0; v < size ; ++v) {

        const dist = Math.sqrt(
          (u/size - 0.5) * (u/size - 0.5) +
          (v/size - 0.5) * (v/size - 0.5))

        if (dist < 0.1) {

          pixels.push(0xff, 0x00, 0x00, 0xff)

        } else if (dist < (radius - 0.05)) {

          pixels.push(0xff, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00)

        } else if (dist < radius) {

          pixels.push(0xff, 0x00, 0x00, 0xff)

        } else {

          pixels.push(0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00)
        }
      }
    }

    const dataTexture = new THREE.DataTexture (
      Uint8Array.from (pixels),
      size, size,
      THREE.RGBAFormat,
      THREE.UnsignedByteType,
      THREE.UVMapping
    )

    dataTexture.minFilter = THREE.LinearMipMapLinearFilter
    dataTexture.magFilter = THREE.LinearFilter // THREE.NearestFilter
    dataTexture.needsUpdate = true

    return dataTexture
  }

  const stopwatch = new Stopwatch()

  let radius = 0.0

  return {
    setTexture: (tex) => {

      const {texture} = shaderParams.uniforms

      texture.value = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(tex)

      texture.needsUpdate = true

    },
    update: () => {

      const dt = stopwatch.getElapsedMs() * 0.001

      radius += dt * 0.25

      radius = radius > 0.5 ? 0.0 : radius

      const {texture} = shaderParams.uniforms

      texture.value = generateTexture(96, radius)

      texture.needsUpdate = true

    },
    material
  }
}
```

[image]